# Negative prefixes: Why impossible but unpleasant?

Tags: prefixes

I know that the negative prefix im- is used before b, m, p as an assimilation of the prefix in-. Then why can't we say *imbelievable*, *inpleasant* or *inpredictable* but we use *unbelievable*, *unpleasant* and *unpredictable*?

Comment: Because English is an exceptional language.

Comment: "Just because!", as various ageing and maddening relatives used to say to me.

Comment: You may have a look at [Negative prefixes](http://grammarist.com/usage/negative-prefixes/) or at [The Cambridge History of the English Language](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CCvMbntWth8C&pg=PA380&lpg=PA380&dq=non-+un+in+negative+prefix+english&source=bl&ots=U1y3VNwHz5&sig=V6VIV9SYmwRqN_Q4RbROxWkB-uc&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCTgKahUKEwjJgfqPmurIAhWDXRoKHQcyAc4#v=onepage&q=non-%20un%20in%20negative%20prefix%20english&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no way of discovering a simple explanation, we can at least look at the linguistic forces that worked on the English language.  The prefix *-un* comes to us from Old English, which was (in the mellifluous words or the *OED*) "freely applied with a purely negative force."  Words that come to us from Old English, (like *belief* from the Old English *gelefan*, to believe) and that had *un-* freely applied to them are likely to retain the form.  The *OED* finds a use of *unbelieved* from the year 1200.  Likewise, words that come to us directly from Latin are likely to retain the Latin negatives *im-* and *in-*: for instance *impotent* from the Latin *impotencia, which comes to us with the negative already implanted.

This neat dichotomy is disrupted by two things.  The first is that we get many words of ultimate Latin origin via Old French, which brought the Latin negative with the Norman Conquest.  Pleasant comes to us from Old French *pleisant*, and although we never said *impleasant*, we once (although rarely) said *impleasing* (from 1602) and *unpleasing* (from 1680).

The second disrupter is that sometimes some words that came to us directly form Latin (e.g., *predict* from the Latin *praedicere*, to foretell, ultimately *pre-*, before + *dicere*, to say) arrived without a commonly-used negative.  Here we have only the rarely used *impredicable* first found in use in 1623.  The forms *predictable* and *unpredictable* arrived in 1857.

I'm afraid that the best we can do is descriptive rather than explicative.  The *OED* tells us that starting in the 14th century, both the Latinate *im-/in-* thrived along with the "native *un-*," with preference for the former only in cases of words of clearly Latin character.  (The *OED* cites *inadequate*, *inadvertence*, and *inarticulate*.)  The golden age of "doublets" lasted until the 17th century, when people started to choose one form and discard the other.  The 18th and 19th centuries saw *un-* become increasingly the popular choice no matter what a word's etymology had to say.  (See *predict* above.)

It's not that the native prefix always prevailed.  The *OED* has first uses of *impossible* and *unpossible* in the 1300s, with the latter "very popular 1200-1400.  (*Possible* is from the Old French *posible*.)  But it's impossible today to use *unpossible* in any but a jocular sense.

Answer (score 2):

Two people have given it as comments, but I will give it as an answer, because that is all the answer you'll get to a "why" question:

**Because that is the way it is.**

There is a bit of historical information you can add to help understand it, which is that *impossible* was borrowed from French, and already had the Latin prefix *in-*, whereas *unpleasant* was formed within English from the French loanword *pleasant*. But there's no reason "why" this should have happened, and no way that you can work it out except by knowing the words.